# Eclipse problem - variables aren't clearing for next run

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a batch id variable that is getting set in the main method for an object.  The next time I run the program with a different batch id parameter. Debugging the output shows that the batch id variable.  I have tried cleaning the project to no avail.  Has anyone run into this or can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: You have to post some sample code for us to help you

Comment: Cleaning the project only rebuilds the class files. I doubt it would help in your situation unless you suspected the classes to be from a previous version. So you really should post code that we can use to reproduce this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the classpath pointing to bin, but Maven was compiling to a target/classes folder.  Thanks for the comments, I didn't post code because it was a just basic setter method.